# Cant install zfc-user with zfc-user-doctrine-mongo-odm

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

when I run `php composer.phar update`
Im getting the error as follows:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-mongo-odm 0.1.1 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-mongo-odm[0.1.1].
- zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-mongo-odm 0.1.1 requires doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module 0.8.* -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:

A typo in the package name
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found a solution. This composer configuration works for me:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm"              : "1.0.0-BETA11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module" : "0.8.1",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.x-dev",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-mongo-odm": "~0.1",
    }
}
```

I hope this help! Nicolas

Comment: You're welcome @gihandilanka. How would you feel about sharing on Github a basic implementation of a User module? This configuration with ODM is not so well documented. That would be a nice use-case. We could build this together.